# Selecting a Returned variable from another function

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which calls another function:

```
for (var index = 0; index < itemsQty; index++) {
                    var itemData = {};
                    page.insertItemDOM(itemData);
                    if (index == 0) {
         // This is where I select newItem and add an active class to it
                    }
}
```

The function called is as follows:

```
    page.insertItemDOM = function (itemData) {
        var newItem = $($("#itemTemplate").html()).clone();
        var targetLoc = $('.carousel-inner');
        targetLoc.attr("data-target", "true");
        targetLoc.append(newItem);

        return newItem;
    }
```

I'm trying to select the first cloned template, and add an active class, but I don't know how to select newItem in the first function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the item and assign it to a variable:

```
  var returnedItem = page.insertItemDOM(itemData);
  // now do what you need with the element
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind it to a variable?

```
var item, itemData;
for (var index = 0; index < itemsQty; index++) {
  itemData = {};
  item = page.insertItemDOM(itemData);
  if (index == 0) {
    $(item).addClass(...);
  }
}
```

<sup>Note: This kind of fundamental non-understanding of how JS works suggests you probably need to go back to [learning about JS](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) or learning about [basic computer programming](http://www.bfoit.org/itp/IntroCmds.html).</sup>